# How to design my controller in storyboard, if it should I have a navigation bar?

Tags: ios, storyboard

This is image our UI give me, the Login interface. You see it have a navigation bar.

[image]

In my storyboard, because the LoginAndRegister.storyboard is new created by me.

Other view controller should push to the Login view controller.So I should not add a navigation bar, or embed in a navigation controller.

[image]

My doubt is that, how can I ignore the navigation bar to design my Login view controller?

Because other controller push to the login view controller, there should auto add a navigation bar upper.

---

**EDIT**

I find some friend misunderstand my requirement.

I have two storyboard, sb1 and sb2. in sb2, there is login view controller.

the login view controller is not the initial view controller, but it should have a navigation bar(see the UI image), the navigation bar is sb1's navigation controller push to login view controller, then it gets the bar. so in the sb2(see upper image), how to design my login view controller(because there is no bar)? should I ignore that?

Comment: You can design navigation bar programmatically.

Comment: Please take a look at this '[how to customize documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationbar/customizing_your_app_s_navigation_bar)', there even is a nice code sample. Hope it helps someone~

Answer (score 0):

you can always show or hide a navigationcontroller's navigationbar (or toolbar) programmatically. add the following to your logincontroller class:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: animated)
}
```

Comment: In the Login storyboard, the Login controller did not embed in a navigation controller, it is shows because of the other navigation controller from other storyboard.

Comment: ok. maybe i got you wrong. do you mean that the login controller is your initial viewcontroller and should not show a navigationbar but every other controller that gets pushed afterwards should show it?

Answer (score 0):

I know whats your meaning, you want to design your view controller in the other storyboard, and the view controller at the time do not have navigation bar , but it should have, because it shows is caused by other navigation controller(**There I called it `origin nav`**) push to.

You want to know how to design like that, and I can tell you, you just embed your new storyboard's view controller in a navigation controller, it will have a navigation bar, it will like what you want, and do not care the navigation bar is not the `origin nav`'s, when you from `origin nav` push to to new storyboard's controller, there is the `origin nav`'s navigation bar on it.